# haskell cgi web programming help

Tags: haskell, forms

I have a form:

```
<div id="form">
     <form action="upload.cgi" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
     </form>
</div>
```

and the upload.cgi is:

```
saveFile n =
    do cont <- liftM fromJust $ getInputFPS "file"
       let f = uploadDir ++ "/" ++ basename n
       liftIO $ writeFile f cont
       return $ paragraph << ("Saved")

uploadDir = "./uploadDirectory"        
basename = reverse . takeWhile (`notElem` "/\\") . reverse
page t b = header << thetitle << t +++ body << b


myFromJust (Just a) = a
myFromJust Nothing  = "gs"


cgiMain = do 
            mn <- getInputFilename "file"
            h <- saveFile (myFromJust mn)
            output . renderHtml $ page "Saved" h

main = runCGI $ handleErrors cgiMain
```

The problem is that every time I try to upload a file instead of saving that file, a file called gs is made(from myFromJust function, if I use fromJust I get Nothing and the program fails) whose contents is the uploaded file name.

So, I try to upload a file called something.zip and i get a file called gs whose contents is something.zip (written as text).

I think the problem is that the getInputFilename "file" or getInputFPS don't return anything but I dont't know why.

Is something wrong with the form or the program?

Comment: Where does `getInputFilename` come from?

Comment: @Antal:Most likely, *getInputFileName* comes from module [Network.CGI](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Practical_web_programming_in_Haskell).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the original code[1](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Practical_web_programming_in_Haskell#File_uploads) uses *POST*; but in the HTML Form of the question, HTML *GET* is used instead.  The fix is to change `GET` to `POST` in the HTML.

From the [original example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Practical_web_programming_in_Haskell) where it uses HTTP *POST*:

```
fileForm =
    form ! [method "post"
           , enctype "multipart/form-data"]
             << [afile "file", submit "" "Upload"]
```

The new Form (partly below) where it improperly uses GET.

```
<form action="upload.cgi" 
      method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Notes**
[1](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Practical_web_programming_in_Haskell#File_uploads) See Section 9: Web/Literature/Practical web programming in Haskel